# pass appAccountToken when subscribe

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase, token, storekit

i need to send "app account token" when I subscribe.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/product/purchaseoption/3749440-appaccounttoken

unfortunately, I could not find an option how to transfer this token at the time of subscription.

I have store manager:

```
import Foundation
import StoreKit


final class StoreManager: NSObject {
    
    static let shared = StoreManager()
    
    let storeObserver = StoreObserver()
    var transactionState: SKPaymentTransactionState?
    var myProducts = [SKProduct]()
    
    private let subscriptionIndentifiers: Set<String> = [
        XXX.Subscription.monthly.productId,
        XXX.Subscription.annual.productId
    ]
    

    private override init() {
        super.init()
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(storeObserver)
    }
    
    func getProducts() {
        let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: subscriptionIndentifiers)
        request.delegate = self
        
        request.start()
    }
    
    func selectedType(type: SubscribeType) {
        switch type {
        case .month:
            purchase(product: myProducts[1])
        case .years:
            purchase(product: myProducts[0])
        }
    }
    
    
    func purchase(product: SKProduct) -> Bool {
               
        if !StoreManager.shared.canMakePayments() {
            return false
        } else {
            if !UserDefaultService.isLogin() {
                return false
            } else {
                let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
                SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)
            }
        }
        return true
    }
    
    func canMakePayments() -> Bool {
        return SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()
    }
}

extension StoreManager: SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKRequestDelegate {
    
    func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
        debugPrint("Did receive response")
        if !response.products.isEmpty {
            for fetchedProduct in response.products {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.myProducts.append(fetchedProduct)
                }
            }
        }
        
        for invalidIdentifier in response.invalidProductIdentifiers {
            debugPrint("Invalid identifiers found: \(invalidIdentifier)")
        }
    }
    
    func requestDidFinish(_ request: SKRequest) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            debugPrint("request did finish ")
        }
    }
}
```

I've seen it done this way:

```
let purchaseResult = try await product.purchase(options: [
                    .appAccountToken(token)
                ])
```

but I can't figure out how to do it in this situation.

Comment: You are using StoreKit 1 framework. App account token is available from StoreKit 2. The former uses `SKProduct` objects, the latter uses `Product` objects. `.purchase(options:)` is not a method of `SKProduct`. Check [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/implementing_a_store_in_your_app_using_the_storekit_api).

Comment: @HunterLion thanks a lot!! and can i use storekit2 without combine? because everywhere I saw the use of storekit 2 was with asunc await and for some reason with combine

Comment: @EvgEnii how did you handle this after all? Did you use applicationUsername instead or did you find a good solution?